# Flutter Wrap widget with ellipsis functionality

Tags: flutter

I want to display some chips on the screen that will have the text. The text can be small or large. And the no of chips can also be 5, 10, etc. So I wrap the list of chip widgets in a Wrap widget.

It looks like the below:

[image]

I want the chip with the text **very very large text** to be on the first line and it must show ellipsis instead of going to the next line. Similarly for the text **very very very very large text**.

How can I achieve that?

This is the code that I'm using:

```
   Wrap(
     spacing: 6.0,
     children: [
       Chip(label: Text("text")),
       Chip(label: Text("large text")),
       Chip(label: Text("very large text")),
       Chip(label: Text("very very large text")),
       Chip(label: Text("very very very large text")),
       Chip(label: Text("very very very very large text"))
     ],
   )
```

Comment: your explanation is very blunt, please be more specific on the end result required

Answer (score 0):

There is no default way to ellipse the text inside `Chip` widget. Better option will wrapping your `Chip` inside a `Container` with width constraints like this.

```
 Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 150.0),
        child: Chip(
            label: Text(
          "very very very very large text very large text 987636236",
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ))),
```

And also you can make the `maxWidth` property dynamic by using the media query. Let know for queries.

[image: Screenshot]

Cheers !!

Comment: Literally not :) @someuser